# Proof about the closed integral $\mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_p]$

Tags: ring-theory, extension-field, p-adic-number-theory, galois-extensions, ramification

Assuming $\zeta_p$ is a root of unit, I need to show that $\cal{O}$$(\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_p))=\mathbb{Z}_p [\zeta_p]$. Where $\cal{O}$$(F)=${$x\in F:|x|_p\le 1$} and $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is the ring of p-adic intageres.

Note that: $\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_p)$ is a totally ramified extention of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ of degree $p-1$

I did manage to show that $\cal{O}$$(\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_p))\supset\mathbb{Z}_p [\zeta_p]$, but not the other way.

I'd love to get some help

Comment: For a detailed Proof see Milne‘s notes on ANT.

Comment: You mean more precisely that $\zeta_p$ is a *primitive $p$-th* root of unity. --- Do you have any ideas? Do you know a prime element of the extension?